# jQuery not working with SVG

Tags: jquery, svg

So I want to fill SVG text with an image for its background. If I set it in the SVG code it works fine. But I want to click a button and then for it to apply the image background to the text. [Here is a fiddle containing all of the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/xWNR3/100/)

Here is the code anyway

```
<body>

<button>Text</button>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>                              
        <pattern id="patt1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
            <image xlink:href="http://dunnrite.co.uk/Images/pattern1.jpg" width="10" height="10" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <text x="20" y="170">Your words here</text>
</svg>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click (function() {
    $("text").css("fill", "url(#patt1)");
});
```

});

Thanks

Comment: working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/xWNR3/102/

Comment: @MohitArora isn't working on latest stable chrome... it is now

Comment: @Mardoxx did you check my demo?

Comment: Yeah that works, sorry, must have used wrong demo :)

Comment: @Mardoxx actually click event not firing in his demo due to absolute position and jquery also not included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your fiddle:

1. You didn't include jQuery.
2. You SVG element overlaps with the button, hence the button is behind the SVG and can't be clicked.

In the CSS drop the `position: absolute; top: 0;` or position it somewhere, without overlapping.

For example like this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" >
<!-- rest of svg code -->
</svg>
```

and

```
svg {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xWNR3/105/)

---

If you want to see for your self, add

```
 background-color: yellow;
```

to the CSS for the SVG and compare both fiddles.